# Xamarin.Forms Master/Detail back stack with Prism

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I'm using Xamarin.Forms with Prism and a Master/Detail to create a "hamburger" menu. When the app runs, I navigate to `NavigationService.NavigateAsync("MyMasterDetailPage/MyNavigationPage/MainPage");`

I have items in the Master flyout menu for navigating to other pages. So I tap one and navigate to `MyNavigationPage/SyncPage`. At this point, if I hit the back button on Android, the app closes. Instead, I'd like to navigate back to the MainPage. I tried to hook into `OnNavigatedFrom` of the SyncPage to force navigation back to MainPage but the app is already closing by the time that event fires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented a solution similar to what Brian suggested but had to add a check to return true if it's the first time through in order to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Implement the INavigationPageOptions interface on MyNavigationPage and set ClearNavigationStackOnNavigation = false

Comment: I changed ClearNavigationStackOnNavigation to false in MyNavigationPage. Now when the app starts up, it navigates to the MainPage but I have a back arrow instead of the hamburger icon. When I press the back arrow, it navigates to an empty page and then the back arrow changes to the hamburger icon. I then navigate to the sync page and get the back arrow again. Pressing the back arrow takes me to an empty page again and brings back the hamburger icon.

Comment: @user5420778 Downvoted for lack of clarity. Instead of one line that says what to do, can you please include how to do what you are saying? I tried to set ClearNavigationStackOnNavigation to false and it says it is a readonly property.